# printing in console from in-proc COM

Tags: c++, com

Is it possible to make COM server write letters to standart console output(i.e. iostream output) when create instance of COM in in-proc way?
I just want to debug it )

Answer (score 1):

Why not use OutputDebugString and Dbgview.exe?

DbgView hooks all current processes for debug messages and shows them in a GUI.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx (DbgView)

It's better than using a log file because you don't have to think about concurrent access to that file.